# Trouble with Mp3 Frames

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio

I'm new to c# .net, I'm working on mp3.

I would like to get the actual data of one frame of an mp3 file, as there is first header, then side information of the frame.

I only need to get the actual bits with no header and ancillary info. 
Can I use NAudio to do this?

I have found an `Mp3FileReader` class and `Mp3Frame` class there, I have also found a RawData variable but don't know how to use them.

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: What do you need mp3 raw data for?

Comment: Raw Data means "Actual data" of mp3 file. No header and side information. @DanielMošmondor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Mp3FileReader.ReadNextFrame` to get at each MP3 raw frame. NAudio's `Mp3Frame` class will tell you some information about the frame, such as sample rate, stereo mode etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
What information RawData gives us about mp3 file? As you know better that there is a frame header then side infomation and at the end there is "Actual Data" of Mp3 file, i only need "Actual Data" to get pitch, frequency and some other information. Can we get that? Another thing is RawData property contains only "Actual Data" of the frame.

Comment: I was asking you why do you need such data since I figured out that you want something that you won't get it so easily.  mp3 raw data is extremely difficult to 'read' since it took many engineers many years to invent how to pack it.  There is no 'pitch' or 'frequency' there that you will be able to magically extract.

Comment: Actually i want to develop a software which can detect a person's voice by checking his voice characteristics. e.g pitch, frequency, magnitude etc